# Как "победить" инкапсуляцию

Tags: c++, инкапсуляция

Обычный пример с юнитом.

```
class Unit {
private:
    int health;

public:
    Unit(int health);
    virtual ~Unit();

protected:
    virtual void setHealth(int newHealth);
```

далее делаем наследника

```
class Healer : public Unit {
public:
    Healer(int health);

    virtual void healing(Unit* other);
};
```

В реализации лечения:

```
void Healer::healing(Unit* other) {
    other->setHealth(100);
}
```

И вот инкапсуляция не разрешает так делать. other->setHealth(100);

> 'setHealth' is a protected member of 'Unit'
>   other->setHealth(newHealth);
>
> can only access this member on an object of type 'Healer' virtual void
>   setHealth(int newHealth);

При этом для this вызвать этот метод можно.

Comment: пробовал переопределять setHealth в наследнике. но это так же не помогло

Comment: сделать публичным

Comment: внутри юнита сделать метод для работы с приватным полем

Comment: Вообще можно сделать `Healer` другом(`friend`) `Unit`, но я вам этого делать не рекомендую. Ваши "победы" над инкапсуляцией приведут к тому что в код станет сложно воносить изменения. Если юниту может менять хп кто-то, кроме самого юнита, то делайте этот метод публичнм, и не водите в заблуждение того, кому придется читать этот код(например будущего себя)

Comment: Ну а если сделать метод публичным, тогда из мэйна изменять ХП смогут все кому не лень. ведь не зря сеттеры делают приватными. а если сделать публичный метод лечения у Юнита, то это тоже архитектурно не правильно, так как лечением занимается только один наследник юнита, а не все его наследники

Answer (score -1):

Мне, кажется, надо добавить вам интерфейс типа `IHealable` например. И, далее, действовать через него. Например сделать ещё один класс `HealableUnit: Unit, IHealable` и в методе `healing` работать с интерфейсом, а не с методом.